# Trying to pull Duplicate data from multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VSiKZbD_PoQTfbav7spalkyBgrt4T8juaLlKOM7LgLM/edit#gid=0

I have two columns, `A` and `B`. Throughout this project, the same name will appear in each column. I want to be able to select the name from the dropdown list, and have it return the proper data.

I have the dropdown list working, the list contains all the names that appear in each column.

When I select "Mike", it returns the proper info, being that Mike appears in `A` and in `B`.
But when I select "John" or "Danny", I get the error message **In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.**

The formula I have in `E8` is

```
={QUERY(A1:B3,"SELECT * WHERE A contains """&E2&"""");QUERY(A1:B3,"SELECT * WHERE B contains """&E2&"""")}
```

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error message you could wrap your formula with the `IFERROR` function:

```
=IFERROR({QUERY(A1:B3,"SELECT * WHERE A contains """&E2&""""); 
         QUERY(A1:B3,"SELECT * WHERE B contains """&E2&"""")}, 
         "No match")
```

[image]

EDIT

> Ok, but there is supposed to match, I'm sorry I'm confused. I'm not looking to just eliminate the error message. Since "John" appears in ColumnA, why is it No Match?

Though the OP's closing question is *"How can I rectify this?"*, I will follow the [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142533/trying-to-pull-duplicate-data-from-multiple-columns-in-google-sheets/142539?noredirect=1#comment130025_142539) and explain.

What you want to do using the curly brackets `{}`, is to have your results displayed one under the other, like `={1;2}`

```
+---+---+------------+--------+--------+
| A | B |  formula   | result | result |
+---+---+------------+--------+--------+
| 1 | 2 | ={1,2;3,4} |        |        |
| 3 | 4 |            |      1 |      2 |
|   |   |            |      3 |      4 |
+---+---+------------+--------+--------+
```

Only in this case, as an example for `John`, because your second query completes with an empty output it is as if you are asking for:

```
+---+---+------------+---------+
| A | B |  formula   | result  |
+---+---+------------+---------+
| 1 | 2 | ={1,2;3, } | #ERROR! |
| 3 |   |            |         |
+---+---+------------+---------+
```

which will result in an `#ERROR!`.
Because you do not have simple numbers but handle queries, you get

> Error
>   In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)

Comment: Ok, but  there is supposed to match, I'm sorry I'm confused. I'm not looking to just eliminate the error message. Since "John" appears in ColumnA, why is it No Match?

Comment: Please check the edited answer.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I see you read my answer. I hope my explanation helped you realize why this particular formula produces the error. In any case let us know.